# Joining two strings by matching positions of alphabet in both strings in Perl

Tags: string, perl

I am trying to write a Perl script where a string get fragmented at every occurrence of 'E' and when user enters positions of 'C' through command line (say 3-8 or 3-8,13-18 or any comma separated such positions of 'C' according to the string in such format if the string is long), the fragments containing 'C' (say at 3 and 8 positions) should be joined and shown in the output. Suppose string is
"ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE" and user enters 3-8 then program oputput should be-

```
ABCDEABCDE
ABCDE
ABCDE
ABCDE
```

I wrote a script where user enters 'C' positions through command line and string get cut at every position of 'E'  but after that I'm not able to write it properly. Please help!

Code (edited) that I've written so far is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $s = 'ABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDEABCDE';
my $i=0;
my @where;
my @array;
my @bond;
my @pos;
my @s_array;
my @s_array2;

for ($i=0; $i<=4; $i++) {
    $where[$i] = index($s,"C",$where[$i-1])+1;
    push(@array,$where[$i]);
}
print "All Positions of C: @array\n\n";
print "Enter C positions:\n";
my @join_C = <STDIN>; 

foreach (@join_C) {
    @bond = split (',',$_);
}

foreach (@bond) {
    @pos = split ('-', $_);
}
print "entered C positions:@pos\n";
print "Resulting disulfide linked peptides\n\n";
my @a = split(/E/, $s); 
my $result = join ("E,", @a);
my @final = split(/,/, $result);
foreach my $final (@final) {
    foreach my $pos(@pos) {
        my @source = split //, $final[@final];
        my $length = @source;
        for ($i=0; $i<=$length; $i++) {
            if (index($final[$i], "C") == $pos[$i]) {
                push (@s_array, $final[$i]);
            }
            else {
                push (@s_array2, $final[$i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
my $lastly_joined = join (',', @s_array);
print "Joined Fragments= @s_array\n";
print "Remaining fragments= @s_array2\n";
```

Comment: 1st- what is @join_C at your code ?
http://codepad.org/3AjVLHhq can you set here $line to string that entered from stdin ?

Comment: @eicto : join_C is an array where all positions of 'C' entered by user for combining strings get stored.

Comment: but how do you use it in your code ?

Comment: @eicto : Sorry, but I can't able to figure it out. My idea is after breaking at every 'E' to match every position of 'C' entered by user with those in the original string. If it get match then two corresponding strings will be shown as joined  in output. But I'm not able to code it properly. Please help!

Comment: did you wrote the code you trying to solve ? it is some homework ?

Comment: @eicto : I have written a code and replaced it with the previous one above. But still I'm not able to get the required result. Please suggest some way.

Comment: @vstm : I have include strict and warnings this time. Now please suggest where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @prashant please use code formating tool when editing question

Comment: can you please rewrite this using hardcoded array with sample input ? and what you epect in output like here http://codepad.org/4s7zxsmX

Comment: What's `$final[@final]` in line #34 of your code as part of the split? I am really having a hard time understanding your requirements. I think you want to split each occurance of `E`. A simple split(/E/, $string) will do that (although it will leave out the `E`, it's easy enough to put it back in). However, I'm not sure what the user input is for. You have a three level `for` loop which is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to understand what you want to do.

> I am trying to write a Perl script where a string get fragmented at every 
>   occurrence of 'E'

Okay, first create the input. Lets use an array to make access to the 
elements easier.

```
my @s = split ('', 'ABCDE' x 5);
```

I'm not sure how that string will look in your case. Can you please provide an 
real world example.

> and when user enters c_pos of 'C' through command line     (say 3-8
>   or 3-8,13-18 or any comma separated such c_pos of 'C' according     to
>   the string in such format if the string is long)

I would suggest to use commandline arguments. That makes it easier to use the
script later in a chain with other tools. Pass the arguments to the script:

> script.pl 3-8,13-18

So we get a list of pairs:

```
my @pairs = split (',', join('', @ARGV));
```

Now you should check that the passed values point to 'C's. Valid combinations
are stored in a hash where the key is the start index and the value is the end
index.

```
my %c_pos; 
foreach my $pair (@pairs) {
   my ($from, $to) = split('-', $pair);
   if (($string[$from-1] eq 'C') && ($string[$to-1] eq 'C')) {
      $c_pos{$from-1} = $to-1;
   } else {
      warn "position ${from}-${to} not valid => ignored!\n";
   }
}
```

> the fragments containing 'C' (say at 3 and 8 positions) should be joined 
>   and shown in the output.

Now we can iterate on the elements of @s. When we hit a start index
   a 'connecion' starts and this connection is active until the end is
   reached.

We store all values to the current entry.

When we hit an 'E' and we are not in a 'connection' the current entry is 
   pushed to our result and we start with the next empty entry.

```
for (my $i=0; $i<@string; $i++) {

   if ($c_pos{$i}) {
       $inside_connection = 1;
       $end = $c_pos{$i}; 
   } elsif ($i == $end) {
       $inside_connection = 0;
       $end = 0;
   }

   $entry.=$string[$i];

   if ($inside_connection) {
      # do not split on 'E'
   } elsif ($string[$i] eq 'E') {
      # split on 'E'
      push @result, $entry;
      $entry = '';
   }
}
```

Because I do not know better I assumed that a chaind connection like 
   3-8, 8-13 will cause that it works like you would have said 3-13. Hope
   that fits. Here is the complete script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @string = split ('', 'ABCDE' x 5);       

my @pairs = split (',', join('', @ARGV));   

my %c_pos; 
foreach my $pair (@pairs) {
   my ($from, $to) = split('-', $pair);
   if (($string[$from-1] eq 'C') && ($string[$to-1] eq 'C')) {
      $c_pos{$from-1} = $to-1;
   } else {
      warn "position ${from}-${to} not valid => ignored!\n";
   }
}

my @result;
my $entry = '';
my $inside_connection = 0;
my $end=0;

for (my $i=0; $i<@string; $i++) {

   if ($c_pos{$i}) {
       $inside_connection = 1;
       $end = $c_pos{$i}; 
   } elsif ($i == $end) {
       $inside_connection = 0;
       $end = 0;
   }

   $entry.=$string[$i];

   if ($inside_connection) {
      # do not split on 'E'
   } elsif ($string[$i] eq 'E') {
      # split on 'E'
      push @result, $entry;
      $entry = '';
   }
} 

print join ("\n", @result);
```